# Alternative ansible syntax

Tags: ansible

I've seen a playbook which looks something like this:

```
- hosts:
  - foo
  - bar
  roles:
    - role: whatever
```

It works, but from the documentation I would have expected that:

a. Hosts would be given as a single space separated line e.g.:

```
- hosts: foo bar
```

rather than a list.

b. The value for the "roles" key in the play would be a list, e.g.:

```
  roles:
    - whatever
```

rather than a key:value pair.

Can someone explain what I'm missing either in yaml which makes these alternatives equivalent once parsed, or where in the ansible docs it explains these alternative definitions?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
For `hosts` use the syntax that you and the other people working with this are most comfortable with.
For `roles`, you need the `role: <name>` syntax only in cases where you want to also set other attributes for the role.

**Longer answer**
I have wondering about this occasionally as well.
In the docs section [Intro to Playbooks, Basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics), it says:

> The `hosts` line is a list of one or more groups or host patterns, separated by colons, as described in the [Working with Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) documentation.

It does, however, not mention explicitly that this list, could also be a space separated string.

As far as the `roles` attribute of a play is concerned, I think the alternate syntax variant is straight forward. If you just pass a name (a single string), then this is obviously the name of the role.

If you want to pass additional arguments, like variables, then you need to create a dictionary. See an example of the two syntaxes used together [here in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) (search for "Roles can accept other keywords").

The definite answer to both questions is in the source code:

Here is the part that parses the `hosts` list in a play:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/play.py#L104-L116

Here is the part that does it for a role in `roles`:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/role/definition.py#L68-L135

There is another hint in the [`playbook/base.py#preprocess_data`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/base.py#L196-L198):

> infrequently used method to do some pre-processing of legacy terms

The `Play` class for example inherits / overrides this method, directly below the snippet I linked to above.